# Inequality for sum of squares

Tags: inequality

let $a_t$ and $b_t$ be any real number. Is the following inequality true?
\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{T} \sum_{t=1}^{T}2a_t^2 + \frac{1}{T} \sum_{t=1}^{T}2b_t^2 > \frac{1}{T} \sum_{t=1}^{T}(a_t + b_t)^2
\end{equation}
Any comments is appreciated.

Comment: Can you say something about the variables?

Comment: Can you do the $T=1$ case?

Comment: For the case $T=1$, what about $a_1=b_1$? You would have to prove $$2a_1^2+2b_1^2>(a_1+b_1)^2$$ $$\iff 4a_1^2>(2a_1)^2=4a_1^2$$ which is obvioulsy false... You might have to prove that $$\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{T} \sum_{t=1}^{T}2a_t^2 + \frac{1}{T} \sum_{t=1}^{T}2b_t^2 \mathbf{≥} \frac{1}{T} \sum_{t=1}^{T}(a_t + b_t)^2
\end{equation}$$

Answer (score 1):

Just observe that

$2a_t^2+2b_t^2-(a_t+b_t)^2=(a_t-b_t)^2\geq0$

That proves your inequality (if you exchange the "$>$" with a "$\geq$").

Answer (score 0):

As I showed in the comments, it doesn't have to be necessarily "bigger", so I'll prove the inequality
$$\frac{1}{T} \sum_{t=1}^{T}2a_t^2 + \frac{1}{T} \sum_{t=1}^{T}2b_t^2 ≥ \frac{1}{T} \sum_{t=1}^{T}(a_t + b_t)^2\;\; a_t,b_t\in\mathbb R \;\text{and} \;T\in\mathbb N$$
Note that
$$\frac{1}{T} \sum_{t=1}^{T}2a_t^2 + \frac{1}{T} \sum_{t=1}^{T}2b_t^2 ≥ \frac{1}{T} \sum_{t=1}^{T}(a_t + b_t)^2\iff\frac{1}{T}\sum^T_{t=1}2a_t^2+2b_t^2≥\frac{1}{T}\sum_{t=1}^T(a_t + b_t)^2$$ 
$$\iff \sum^T_{t=1}2a_t^2+2b_t^2≥\sum_{t=1}^T(a_t + b_t)^2$$ 
$$\iff2a_t^2+2b_t^2≥(a_t+b_t)^2\iff a_t^2+b_t^2≥2a_tb_t\iff a_t^2+b_t^2-2a_tb_t≥0$$
Which obviously holds for every $a_t,b_t\in\mathbb R$ since
$$a_t^2+b_t^2-2a_tb_t=(a_t-b_t)^2≥0$$

Comment: Thank you very much Dr. Mathva!

Comment: @MikeL you can also upvote the answer if you liked it ;)